# Find all posts with more than a defined number of comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple rails 3 blog app where posts have many comments and comments belong to a post.

I want to create a scope that will fetch all posts that have more than 5 comments.
What's the best way of doing this without a counter cache column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this, perhaps?

```
Post.select('posts.*, count(comments.id) as comment_count').
  joins(:comments).
  group('posts.id').
  having('comment_count > 5')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It only returns the first record. Also the comment_count is set to the total count of all comments in the db.

Comment: I've updated it to include a GROUP BY clause. Does that fix it for you?

Comment: Note also that you should be able to call `post.comment_count` on each of the returned records.

Answer (score 6):

In **Postgres 9.1** I had to set things up like this as postgres isn't happy putting conditions on calculated fields or something like that.

```
Post.select('posts.*, count(comments.id) as comment_count').
  joins(:comments).
  group('posts.id').
  having('count(comments.id) > 5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from noodl... thanks for that!

I needed to find - to stick with the example classes of the original question - the 4 posts that were most recently commented on... a slight variant of noodl's answer does the trick:

```
Post.select('posts.*, max(comments.created_at) as last_commented_at').
  joins(:comments).
  group('posts.id').
  order('last_commented_at DESC').
  limit(4)
```

Thanks!