# User has_many posts. Get all users that have at least 1 post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Users have_many posts.

In a view, I want to get an alphabetized list of all users that have at least 1 post. Here is how I currently do it. Is there a way to make this all one line / using better Rails ActiveRecord conventions?

```
@users.order("name ASC").each do |user|
  if user.posts > 0
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: You can take a look at this and modify it accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314987/find-all-posts-with-more-than-a-defined-number-of-comments

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution isn't bad (it's a single query) but it can be improved.

You can use ActiveRecord's built-in counter cache functionality to store the number of associated objects on the parent (in this case, the number of posts associated with a user). Then you can craft a query like this:

```
User.where('posts_count > 0').order('name ASC')
```

Here are the docs on `:counter_cache` ([taken from here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)):

> :counter_cache
>
> Caches the number of belonging objects on the associate class through the use of increment_counter and decrement_counter. The counter cache is incremented when an object of this class is created and decremented when it's destroyed. This requires that a column named #{table_name}_count (such as comments_count for a belonging Comment class) is used on the associate class (such as a Post class) - that is the migration for #{table_name}_count is created on the associate class (such that Post.comments_count will return the count cached, see note below). You can also specify a custom counter cache column by providing a column name instead of a true/false value to this option (e.g., counter_cache: :my_custom_counter.) Note: Specifying a counter cache will add it to that model's list of readonly attributes using attr_readonly.

Answer (score 1):

We can get all the user ids which have atleast one post using this.

```
Post.uniq.pluck(:user_id);
```

And then we can fetch all the user as follows.

```
 User.order(:name).find(Post.uniq.pluck(:user_id));
```

Comment: This generates two database calls. The code in the question is only one, so performance-wise I'd say it's a better option than this

Answer (score 0):

`User.joins(:posts).order('users.name asc')` will perform an inner join, as described in the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins). A counter cache isn't a bad solution either.

Comment: Using a join is a great idea if you plan on using the posts associated with the users in the same action.

Comment: Well, no, if you want to actually retrieve the posts, you need `includes`. `joins` is useful if you want to filter on something to do with the posts later in the scope chain, or if, as here, you want to filter on their mere existence.