# Scope to filter records with at least 3 "recent" polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am working on a rails4 application that has `Publication`, `Observation` and `Species` models, of which the records can be "validated" by users (Devise `User` model) through a polymorphic association (`Validation` model).

Publications (and their metadata through associated HABTM models) are considered "validated" if the publication is validated by at least three users since the publication was last updated (i.e. `validation.updated_at >= publication.updated_at` for at least 3 validations). This criteria is implemented so that if information on the publication changes after being validated by users, those specific "outdated" validations are not counted, until revalidated by the user (through a `touch` on the association).

I am trying to figure out how I can produce a `scope :validated` and `scope :unvalidated` for the `Publication` model (i.e. filtering only the publications that are validated).

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users        // authors of that publication
  has_many :validations, as: :validatable
  has_many :validation_users, through: :validations, source: :user
 end

class Validation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :validatable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :validations
end
```

I can retrieve Publications with at least 3 validations like below (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4315084/7853850)) - however how could I best retrieve (preferably as a scope) only those with at least 3 validations updated after the last update of the publication?

```
Publication.select("publications.*, count(validations.id) as validations_count").joins(:validations).group("publications.id").having("validations_count > 2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the mentioned condition:

```
Publication.
  select("publications.*, count(validations.id) as validations_count").
  joins(:validations).
  where("validations.updated_at >= publications.updated_at").
  group("publications.id").
  having("validations_count > 2")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried that, but now found out it did not work before because of a `@publications.count` in my view (that generated a SQL error). Would you know why I cannot perform a `.count` on the result? Also - to do the reverse (to find the unvalidated records), I assume I need to do a left join (`include`) to also include publications with 0 validations - however that gives issues with the `validations_count`? How could I get around that?

Comment: 1. `count` is a special word in Rails, probably better to rename column, for example, to `counter`.  2. In Rails 5.0 you may call `left_joins(:validations)`, in Rails 4.2- you need to write join as string `joins("LEFT JOIN validations ON publications.id = validations.publication_id")`. Also you should remove `having` condition.